# How to check mod flag process that I flag one of user message on chat?

Tags: discussion, flags, chat, moderator-tools

I do search about my question did not find any info about mod flag review state so I put this question.

If I put mod flag from chat against one user who misused chat room Feature of Stack Overflow. After I flag I also mention the reson of flag then click on sent button. After that how can I know about this flag process or status like what moderate take action.

I can not see this flag status like we flag on question or answer and that status display in our profile flag-summary.

How can I know that status of my chat flags?

Answer (score 2):

You can't follow the status of chat moderator flag like you can on the main site. There is no view available for that in chat.

You simply have to trust that a moderator will see your flag and handle it. Depending on which chat server you are using at that moment, you either have all of the Stack Overflow moderators to handle the flag, if it's on https://chat.stackoverflow.com; or on https://chat.stackexchange.com you have all moderators across all sites to handle chat flags; and on https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com you have a lot of Stack Exchange staff (devs / CM's) to attend to your flags. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303841/158100) from [Mithrandir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/294691/mithrandir) for how a moderator will see your flag.

If you raise moderator flags that aren't warranted too often, I'm sure a moderator will have a chat with you...