# Who is able to see who raised a chat flag?

Tags: support, privileges, chat-flags

I am just curious whether flags in chat rooms are anonymous or who is able to see which user raised them.

I can personally see chat flags in the SE chat rooms due to >10k SE network reputation, but there is no "author" mentioned.

Can room owners see who raised the flag? Or moderators?

Comment: A room owner can't see who raised a flag.

Comment: Based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270268/158100) I would say moderators can't see who raised a normal chat flag either: *On offensive flags, we[mods] see only what 10k users see - which is only which message the flag was cast against.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: At some point, the system was changed so that all moderators on the server (e.g. chat.SE) can see who raised a flag, irrespective of the moderator's site of origin or the room that the flag was raised in. This was changed at some point in either 2020 or 2021.

---

Original answer, as of 2017:

This depends on a couple things.

If a moderator *on the site that a room is hosted on* is *in the room* at the *time that the message was flagged*, they can see who flagged the message. If they weren't there, they can't see it anymore. They can't see it after the fact, and mods who aren't mods on the site that the room is hosted in can't see who flagged it.

So, for instance, if you flag something in [The Reading Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room) (the main chatroom for Literature.SE, where I'm a mod) while I'm actively in the room, and I manage to catch the blue flag before it's handled I can see who flagged it. But if [Rand al'Thor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/131071/rand-althor) is in the room (who's a moderator on Scifi.SE) at the time, and catches the flag, they won't see who flagged it.

[image]

But if it's in [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) (the main Scifi.SE chatroom), it's the opposite - Rand al'Thor will be able to see who flagged the message, but I won't.

If you moderate multiple sites, and your chat parent is set to one of those sites, and someone flags a message in a room parented to a site that you moderate that is not the site that *your* chat parent is set to, [you can see who flagged it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41439485#41439485). ...That is to say, [Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/139041/catija) moderates both [Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) and [Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange](https://crafts.stackexchange.com). If something in [The Studio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/the-studio) (the main chatroom for Crafts.SE) gets flagged, she can still see who flagged it, even though her parent site is set to Interpersonal.SE. She can also see flags in [The Awkward Silence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) (the main Interpersonal.SE chatroom).

And of course, CMs [have ways of finding out who flagged a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41439323#41439323), even after the fact. (The majority of users won't be able to see that link. It's a mod-only link, sorry. But it's a response from a CM that clearly indicates that they have a way of seeing who flagged a message when necessary.)

Regular mods can see a list of which messages have been recently flagged, and the number of flags it received (including flags (includes 'valid' clicks), counterflags ('invalid' clicks), meh flags ('not sure'), and custom mod flags). That list is located at [`/admin/recent-flags`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/recent-flags) (link 404s for non mods). This list doesn't include the information about who flagged it, though.

Custom mod flags look a bit different. They show up as orange or red (I'm still not sure when it shows as orange or red, it seems inconsistent), and these always show the name of the flagger:

[image]

Comment: Nice late answer, thanks. It's apparently even more complex than I'd have imagined :P

Comment: We're still doing some science on what happens with users who mod multiple sites and trying to drag Shog into it ;)

Comment: If a moderator's message is flagged and that moderator is still in the room can they see who flagged their message?

Comment: @RobertLongson - I'm... not sure. I'd offer to test it, but unfortunately I can't now. Perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: @RobertLongson I remember a moderator once testing this (with unfortunate effects), and I *think* the answer was yes, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The dot color is just related to the site theme.... SFF is red, most other sites are orange.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this.

Comment: Man, the users chosen for the examples here and with their moderator statuses have not aged well (Rand is now a mod on Lit.SE, and Catija's a CM) :P

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing - Such is the danger of using real-world examples. :)

Comment: I believe that the information you've added is incorrect, at least for private rooms.

Comment: @Makyen - Private rooms are still a separate matter, yes.